# EventMachine: "`start_tcp_server': no acceptor (port is in use or requires root privileges)"

Tags: ruby, tcp, port, eventmachine

When I try and run the server with `EventMachine::run` I keep getting the error saying that the port is in use. This started ever since I ran the server in the background with the command `nohup`.

I am pretty sure I have killed the process I started:

- I found the ruby process with `ps`, and killed it. It no longer shows up.
- I also ran `lsof -i :8081` (8081 is the port I ran it on) and nothing shows up.
- Finally, I have changed the port in the ruby program a number of times to obscure ports, and *still* get the error!

I also thought it could be the lack of me being the root user, so tried it as root to no avail.

I have also restarted the server.

Please let me know if there's anything else I can try.

Note: this is on debian.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have finally figured it out: it was actually the IP address I was binding to that was incorrect!

So essentially it is a very misleading error message, and if you get it, check the IP address too.

Comment: For me it helped changing rails s -b 0.0.0.0 to -b 127.0.0.1

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize this :)

Comment: This is exactly what happened to me. The computer switched to another wifi network without me noticing.

Answer (score 51):

Had the same problem.

Ran `lsof -i :3000` (3000 is the port I ran it on).

I found out that the port was being used by ruby. I killed the process using `kill -9 *pid*`.

When I ran `lsof -i :3000` again, nothing showed up.

I then ran `rails s` and everything works fine now.

Comment: Worked for me too - added to my mental list of future workarounds. Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

It happens when you didn't stop your server correctly, for example when suspended with Ctrl+Z or running the server twice.

If stopped by Ctrl+Z, this works for me:

Get the running process with:

```
$ ps ax | grep rails
18192 pts/28 Sl+  0:05 /home/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby bin/rails c
20496 pts/23 Tl 0:08 /home/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby bin/rails s
20919 pts/23 S+ 0:00 grep --color=auto rails
```

And then kill the process in which `rails server` running:

```
$ kill 20496
```

If it's not closed after a few seconds you can try to "force" close with with `-9` (but this prevents any cleanup from Rails):

```
$ kill -9 20496
```

Now you can start the server again:

```
$ rails s
```

Comment: You can also use `fg` to bring the process to the foreground again :-)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will save someone's time:
In my case rails server won't start on any port returning the same error.
Event after restarting my machine.
Other servers that refer to localhost didn't work as well.

The problem was in my `/etc/hosts` file that somehow became empty. After restoring it to default state the problem was solved.

Answer (score -1):

Running on free port solves the problem by either:

```
rails s -p 3001
```

or

```
ruby script/rails server webrick -e production -p 3001
```

or

```
ruby script/rails server thin -e production -p 3001
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case it was just internet connection issues.